# Display Images from C: drive which path is define in web config file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I need to display the images in web browser which path define in web config file in c# language.

**My Web Config File**

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="FilePath" value="C:/Images/"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: You can't serve files from an arbitrary folder without reading in the file and presenting it to the client as a stream. Why not just places the folder inside your solution?

Comment: why its not possible ?

Comment: Please add more detail to the question about why your code is not working, if you are receiving any error messages and what you have tried so far to attempt to solve the problem.